# How to render Html in react-native and alter the data?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to alter the content of the html coming from the api.

I will use some example html in this case

```
const htmlContent = `
    <h1>This HTML snippet is now rendered with native components !</h1>
    <h2>Enjoy a webview-free and blazing fast application</h2>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dHLmxfO.jpg?2" />
    <em style="textAlign: center;">Look at how happy this native cat is</em>
`;
```

Here is the example html.
What I want to do is i want to replace the the word `Enjoy` with `Do Not Enjoy` and display them when the component is rendered.

The package I am using is called [React-native-render-html](https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-render-html) to render the html.

This is how i rendered the html

```
export default function Demo() {
  const contentWidth = useWindowDimensions().width;
  return (
    <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <HTML source={{ html: htmlContent }} contentWidth={contentWidth} />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

There is a documentation in there stated that we can use these code to alter the data but
I don't know how to use them for my specific case. Can some one help?

```
// ... your props
alterData: (node) => {
  let { parent, data } = node;
  if (parent && parent.name === "h1") {
    return data.toUpperCase();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `alterData` method, you get the content html as `data`. You can modify this to match your needs.

In your case, we can use the `replace` method to replace all instances of "Enjoy" to "Do not Enjoy".

```
<HTML
  source={{ html: htmlContent }}
  contentWidth={contentWidth}
  alterData={(node) => {
    let { parent, data } = node;
      return data.replace("Enjoy", "Do not Enjoy");
  }}
/>
```

If you want, you can use the `parent` parameter to determine which tags to update or skip.